# How to remove all elements in array A from array B?

Tags: lua

```
local a = {1, 2, 3}
local b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
-- I need b - a = {4, 5, 6}
```

I want to remove all elements from array `b` that are also present in array `a`. Looking for FASTEST solution.

Comment: Do you want to remove in place or create a new table with just the missing elements?

Comment: Faster approach. There might be ~100-1000 elements in each table.

Comment: Creating a new table is likely to be *much* faster.

Comment: When you say "array", do you mean "sequence"? ["We use the term sequence to denote a table where the set of all positive numeric keys is equal to {1..n} for some non-negative integer n, which is called the length of the sequence."](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1). Regardless, be aware that many of the solutions assume that the inputs are sequences. Your sample output is also a sequence but if you don't need that, in-place modification could be faster.

Answer (score 4):

Invert the smaller table into a hash and compare against it in a loop.

```
function invtab(t)
    local tab = {}
    for _, v in ipairs(t) do
        tab[v]=true
    end
    return tab
end

local a = {1, 2, 3}
local b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

local ainv = invtab(a)

-- To get a new table with just the missing elements.
local ntab = {}
for _, v in ipairs(b) do
    if not ainv[v] then
        ntab[#ntab + 1] = v
    end
end

-- To remove the elements in place.
for i = #b, 1, -1 do
    local v = b[i]
    if ainv[v] then
        table.remove(b, i)
    end
end
```

Comment: Wow great. I forgot to mention that each array will be a SET in fact (there won't be duplicates) - do you think it is possible to speed up the code with this assumption?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Storing the sets as hashes in the first place will help as it means you can avoid the inversion step (which costs a table iteration, table creation, and table allocation(s)).

Answer (score 4):

This code copies the duplicate keys over to array c

```
local a = {1, 2, 3}
local b = {1, 2, 3, 4,5 ,6}
local c = {}

for k,v in ipairs(b) do
    local foundkey = false
    for _k,_v in ipairs(a) do
        if _v == v then 
            foundkey = true 
        end
    end
    if foundkey then 
        table.insert(c,v)
    end
end
```

Or

```
local a = {1, 2, 3}
local b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

for k,v in ipairs(b) do
    local key = 0
    for _k,_v in ipairs(a) do
        if _v == v then 
            key = _k
        end
    end
    if key ~= 0 then 
        table.remove(a,key )
    end
end

-- Outputs a = {7}
```

or

```
local a = {1, 2, 3}
local b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
local c = {}

for k,v in ipairs(b) do
    local foundkey = 0
    for _k,_v in ipairs(a) do
        if _v == v then 
            foundkey = _k
        end
    end
    if foundkey == 0 then 
        table.insert(c,v)
    end
end
a = c

-- Output a = {4, 5, 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use stack here. when just compare two indexes that are not same push into stack. stack.

Comment: Can't do like that, because both arrays items might not be sorted, and length of "a" might be also greater than length of "b"

Comment: length of two arrays does't matter here.

Comment: you just choose one array e.g we have array named A and want to remove from it which is not in B so you just sort them using any algo but if the array is large then use quick sort and then finally do as i said at first.

Comment: Please edit your answer to change/add details, comments are not a good place to have an answer. Also please try to ensure your solution is likely to solve the problem, don't provide guesses if you might not be able to solve the issue.